# Assets not cosidering base href url - not found error

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, href, assets, radix

I just copied my angular build scripts within my webform project and deployed that project in IIS.

Note: I have only copied scripts file not deployed separately inside the IIS.

I have copied angular dist folder inside the Scripts folder in webform project.

Right now my base url is:
http://localhost/Angular2/

In Angular I have set the **base href** to **"../../Scripts/dist"** inside ***index.html*** file.

Everything is working fine like routing, loading images, js files etc. Only svg icons are not getting loaded and getting **404 Not Found** error.

For Angular page, except svg, everything(css,jpg,js) is loaded from 
**http://localhost/Angular2/Scripts/dist/main.js** etc.

But the svg icons are trying to get load from path
**http://localhost/Angular2/assets/features/home.svg** in stead of **http://localhost/Angular2/Scripts/dist/assets/features/home.svg**

I am not sure why for svg icons, base href is not working.

Below is the code where I am using svg icons using material library.

```
constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('home', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/features/home.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('library', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/features/library.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('guest', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/features/guest.svg'));
```

If I modified the above lines with the below one then it is working fine.

```
constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('home', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('Scripts/dist/assets/features/home.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('library', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('Scripts/dist/assets/features/library.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('guest', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('Scripts/dist/assets/features/guest.svg'));
```

May I know why base href is not applying for svg icons?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

try using relative paths:

changing

```
'/assets/features/home.svg'
```

to

```
'./assets/features/home.svg'
```

your code:

```
constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('home', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/features/home.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('library', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/features/library.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('guest', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/features/guest.svg'));
```